# Best svn strategy to include nuget and third party libraries to repository

Tags: svn, nuget, visualsvn-server, ankhsvn

I am using Visual Studio and nuget packages.

I am starting to use svn for all my work.

I am not willing to let nuget download the packages on build time. I want to keep the packages directory committed to the repository.

If i check out the project just to update the nuget packages and immediately commit them adding a tag, hat means that i have a trunk version with previous nuget packages?

Also nuget seems not to delete the old packages after update. I would delete the directories manual and commit. Correct?

In general what should be my correct strategy if wanted to keep nuget packages in repository?

Comment: Have you considered hosting your own private, local NuGet repository with the versions of the packages you want? That way you can control what versions are in use, don't have to pull from the internet, and most importantly, you're not managing 3rd-party binary files in your repository (which can become a major pain).

Comment: I havent gone that far as i think i dont need it. How it could become a pain exactly?

Comment: Binaries will bloat your repository & working copies tremendously. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14527653/1324345) for hosting your own NuGet repository/feeds. You'll probably end up finding a lot of good uses for it.