# Reference all required assemblies for runtime or compile time?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I thought this would have been a question already asked many times, but I can't find it.

We are developing applications and have multiple shared assemblies which are used by multiple targets. When I'm creating a new application I'll probably use such a assembly (eg Framework) and reference it in my project. All fine here. However, when this Framework assembly uses for example the Model assembly, I'm not forced by Visual Studio to reference it. As long as my code doesn't touch any Model types, it will compile fine without a reference.

At runtime, it does require the Model assembly. When **releasing** this application there is no problem, as I just include all the required references in my installer project.

The problem arrizes when I try to **debug** the application. The bin folder won't have the Model assembly as it's not referenced.

**The question**
Is there a best practice to solve this "reference of a reference" situation?

**Solutions we've come up with**

*Add the Model as a reference*
This feels wrong, we pollute the project

*Include the Model project in the solution and add as project reference*
This feels even worse (polluting the solution)

*Add post-build step*
Could be a solution, but doesn't feel that right either.

Comment: What is your actual problem? All standard MSBuild build tasks are able to resolve references and copy all required assemblies (not only directly referenced).

Comment: Just to clarify: Your project A references an assembly B, which *should* reference an assembly C, but you can compile A as long as it references B, even though B does not reference C?

Comment: Remember that an assembly is supposed to be the "unit of deployment". So if the assembly `Framework.dll` always requires you to have assembly `Model.dll` around, then probably you'd be better off having both as one single-file assembly. If `Model.dll` is used internally by `Framework.dll`, and by no other project, you could consider merging it into `Framework.dll` using [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx).

Comment: @oryol: Agreed. (But there are exceptions. For example P/Invoke DLL function references (I suppose), or that build tools are unlikely to detect run-time dependencies, such as when an assembly loads another using reflection.)

Comment: Added some clarification to my question, hope that helps.

Comment: @oryol: The problem is that when I'm in VS and debug the application, it will throw an exception telling me that assembly "Model" is necessary.

Comment: @Kjartan: A refs B, B refs C, but VS doesn't force you to add a ref to C unless you use a type from it. However, runtime, it does need C to work correctly.

Comment: @stakx: Good point, but the assemblies all specify as "unit of deployment", they're used by multiple targets, joining them won't work (eg Model is required by Framework, but Model is also required by Core, which at his turn doesn't need Framework). If the scenario is still unclear, let me know, I'll change the question a bit.

Comment: @TomKuijsten: No, it's quite clear. However I, like some others above me, am surprised that VS doesn't detect the assembly's internal dependency on another assembly. Do you think it would be possible to post a minimal example of a multi-project/assembly solution that exhibits this problem?

Comment: @stakx: That's just not how VS works, it will only copy the referenced assembly, not it's dependencies. It's not even possible for VS to do that, because it doesn't know where to find the reference dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this is to package your `Framework` or `Library` assemblies (or sets) with [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/). You can then use NuGet in Visual Studio to take care of all these references. This works great, even when using nested dependencies.

NuGet is fully supported and integrated into Visual Studio. It is very easy to host your own package repository (that can be as simple as pointing to a file share with packages).

You can host a private on-site repository for your own (internal) pacakges. That's what most shops do. You can combine that with one or more public NuGet repositories for public things as Log4Net etc..

And while it may seem to take some time to get this up and running (which is relative, try to just use a public package first just to get the hang of using NuGet first), you get a whole lot of benefits as well. For example, you get support for versioning your libraries out of the box.

At my company we've had this problem for years, and we used to build and check-in library assemblies (50+) into source control, and dragging that around across branches. Since we've switched out approach to using NuGet, this problem just gone away for us. Never looking back to that anymore.

Comment: Feels like a lot of plumbing for something simple, or am I wrong? Another thing is that it will be public for everyone right? Not sure I want that.

Comment: @TomKuijsten It's very simple to set up your own private repository. See [Can I publish a private NuGet package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527615/can-i-publish-a-private-nuget-package). I personally have moved all my "utility projects" so that they're served via NuGet, as the versioning makes it simple to have multiple projects reference a single one, and you can change the assembly without breaking other applications.

Comment: That would be a nice solution, gonna take a look at that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we are started a POC using private nuget repository.

Answer (score 0):

A reference to another project does not necessarily need to be a Project reference. In your example, reference Model as a Bin reference within Framework. This way a pre-built Model will be included with the build of Framework.

Comment: Don't really understand how this would help in my situation. If that pre-built Model is included, I still need to hard-reference it in my new application to be copied to my bin folder right?